# QApplication constructor (Qt) takes up to 10 seconds

Tags: qt, multi-touch

I have finished my first Qt application, and noticed that the **QApplication constructor in the main.cpp files take up to 10 seconds** to execute. This results in an annoying startup delay where I can't even show a splash screen.

When profiling this delay it turns out that the **initializeMultitouch_sys method in the QApplicationPrivate class is the culprit**. Specifically, the iInkTablets->get_Count(...) call takes all the time.

```
void QApplicationPrivate::initializeMultitouch_sys()
{
    [...]
    IInkTablets *iInkTablets = 0;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(QT_CLSID_InkTablets, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, QT_IID_IInkTablets, (void**)&iInkTablets);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        long count = 0;
        iInkTablets->get_Count(&count);   // <== Takes 5-10 seconds!!
        for (long i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

I am using Windows 7, but not utilizing any multi-touch feature. Any idea what causes this problem and how I can avoid it?

Thanks,
Fabian

**UPDATE 2010-11-14 - PROBLEM SOLVED**

I noticed that the problem then occured with all Qt based applications, including Qt Designer. A reboot fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in 4.6.3 ([QTBUG-6007](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-6007)/[commit](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/commit/d7513a5994c734ed48e95ec55d1abd9147c75405))